# Can I run linux mint without installing it? Or does the selection in the grub already run it without installing?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

When I have a linux mint bootable usb drive in my computer, it asks if I want to install linux mint, or install linux mint configuration (I think that's that, I don't feel like replacing ubuntu with mint) in the grub.  When I have ubuntu on the drive, it gives me the option to run it without installing.  This is not included with linux mint.  Instead of risking all my files being gone (and then taking the time to restore them), I decided to ask the experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes** if you choose an install option it will start the process of installing to disk which could overwrite your hard drive if that process is completed.

***Instead you could***:
The following link will show you how to setup a persistent USB installation of Linux Mint.  A persistent USB installation is a lot like an installation on a removable hard drive, and unlike a Live-CD your changes will persist between reboots.

> http://tuxtweaks.com/2014/03/create-linux-mint-persistent-live-usb/

Note: This write up is using Mint as the base from which to create the USB installation but you should be able to follow along easy enough from your Ubuntu installation.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The regular Linux Mint ISO's should all have options that just run Mint "live", and once it's running there's an icon on the Desktop to "Install Linux Mint". So if it boots correctly and gets to a Desktop, it ***is*** running live, without being installed.

You can still install some new programs and save files, but everything is in RAM and any changes not written to a physical drive are lost on reboot. Persistence would allow installed programs and some files to be saved directly to the bootable USB, but it's not necessary to run live.

How did you create your Bootable USB anyway? There is no "Install Mint" from the default boot menu options on the 17.2 ISO, just these (basically the same but either isolinux or grub depending on how it's booted or the media I think):

grub.cfg contains:

```
menuentry "Start Linux Mint 17.2 Xfce 32-bit" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Start Linux Mint 17.2 Xfce 32-bit (compatibility mode)" {
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper xforcevesa iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} ramdisk_size=1048576 root=/dev/ram rw noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check the integrity of the medium" {
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  boot=casper integrity-check iso-scan/filename=${iso_path} quiet splash --
    initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

isolinux.cfg has:

```
label live
  menu label Start Linux Mint
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
menu default
label xforcevesa
  menu label Start in compatibility mode
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper xforcevesa nomodeset b43.blacklist=yes initrd=/casper/initrd.lz ramdisk_size=1048576 root=/dev/ram rw noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll --
label forcepaeoption
  menu label Start with PAE forced
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash -- forcepae
label check
  menu label Integrity check
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  boot=casper integrity-check initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
label memtest
  menu label Memory test
  kernel /casper/memtest
label local
  menu label Boot from local drive
  COM32 chain.c32
  APPEND hd0
```